# Creating cv2.VideoCapture() object directly from numpy array image data

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, ubuntu-18.04, ros

The purpose is to take data from a virtual camera (from a camera in Gazebo simulation, updating every second) and use [Detectron2](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/master/demo/demo.py) (requires data come from cv2.VideoCapture) to recognize other objects in the simulation. The virtual camera of course does not appear in `lspci` so I can't simply use cv2.VideoCapture(0).

So my code is

```
bridge = CvBridge()
cv_image = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, desired_encoding='bgr8') #cv_image is numpy.ndarray, size (100,100,3)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
ret, frame = cap.read(image=cv_image)
print(ret, frame)
```

but it just prints `False None`, I assume because there's nothing being captured in cap. I

f I replace line 2 with `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cv_image)` I get the error,

`TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

since I believe it requires either and integer (representing webcam number) or string (representing video file).

And for reference,

```
cv_image = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, desired_encoding='bgr8') # cv_image is numpy.ndarray
cv2.imshow('image', cv_image)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

displays the image perfectly fine. Could there be a way to use imshow() or something similar as input for VideoCapture()?

However, `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.imshow('image', cv_image))`opens a blank window and gives me,

```
[ERROR:0] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (116) open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.2.0) /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp:293: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_filename.empty() in function 'open'
```

How can I create a `cv2.VideoCapture()` object that can use the image data that I have? Or what's something that might point me in the right direction?

Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.6 with opencv-python 4.2.0.34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to rewrite Detectron2's --input flag in the demo to constantly run a ROS2 callback with `demo.run_on_image(cv_data)`. So instead of making it process video, it just quickly processes each new image one at a time. This is a workaround so that `cv2.VideoCapture()` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

From what I found on [Gazebo tutorials page](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins):

In Rviz, add a ''Camera'' display and under ''Image Topic'' set it to `/rrbot/camera1/image_raw`.

In your case it probably won't be /rrbot/camera1/ name, but the one you are setting in .gazebo file

```
<cameraName>rrbot/camera1</cameraName>
<imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
<cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
```

So you can create subscriber and use `cv2.VideoCapture()` for every single image from that topic.

Comment: Well I have a callback subscribed to that topic, but my concern is more `cv2.VideoCapture(what_goes_here_to_read_from_topic)`

Comment: Oh I see, there is another option. As far as I know `cv2.VideoCapture()` argument can be either the device index or the name of a video file, if you are subscribed to the camera/image_raw, you can read it with `cv2.imread()` method which loads an image from the specified file. But before passing argument to `cv2.imread()` you have to convert it from sensor_msgs/Image to cv-readable object.

Comment: don't forget to import cv_bridge.
`from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError`
and then you good to go with:
`bridge = CvBridge()`
`cv_image = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")`, now you have an object cv_image which can be `cv2.imread()` argument.